# Newbie: Basic Communication using Simulink and USRP2 devices

Tags: matlab, simulink, usrp

I would like to start a semester project related to Matlab Simulink and USRP devices. I am new in this field and studying regularly about it...

The first step to setup the devices is completed and now I would like to check if both device can communicate properly. For this Reason can any one suggest a simple Communication Module...

anything would be OK to start with. e.g sending text, Image, Voice, Video etc etc...

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the communications toolbox in matlab:

[USRP® Support Package from Communications System Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.se/hardware-support/usrp.html)

There seem to be some code snippets for simulink available as well.

BR
Magnus